# How can make excution for the Apex Class Action in Open Execute Anonymous Window

Tags: salesforce, apex

I would like to execute this apex class in the debug "Open Execute Anonymous Window":

ExternalDriveUploadRunAction apex class is to process the External Drive Upload record.

Code is as below:

```
public with sharing class ExternalDriveUploadRunAction {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Run an External Drive File Upload' description='Processes the External Drive Upload Request')

    public static void execute (List<External_Drive_Upload__c> externalDriveUploads) {
        List<ExternalDriveUploadQueueService.Request> requests = new List<ExternalDriveUploadQueueService.Request>();
        ExternalDriveUploadQueueService service = new ExternalDriveUploadQueueService();

        for (External_Drive_Upload__c externalDriveUpload : externalDriveUploads) {
            ExternalDriveUploadQueueService.Request request = 
                new ExternalDriveUploadQueueService.Request(externalDriveUpload);
            requests.add(request);
        }
        service.sendAsync(requests);
    }
}
```

My execution and calling the ExternalDriveUploadRunAction method is as below:

```
List<External_Drive_Upload__c> requests = new List<External_Drive_Upload__c>{'ID'};
ONOW_ExternalDriveUploadRunAction.execute(requests);
```

But above execution calling is showing the error like below:

```
Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected: External_Drive_Upload__c but was: String
```

I would like to know the called execution method.

Answer (score 0):

What do you get with

```
List<External_Drive_Upload__c> requests = new List<External_Drive_Upload__c>{
   new External_Drive_Upload__c(Id = 'id goes here')
};
ONOW_ExternalDriveUploadRunAction.execute(requests);
```

or

```
ONOW_ExternalDriveUploadRunAction.execute([SELECT Id, Name
FROM External_Drive_Upload__c 
WHERE Id = 'id goes here']);
```